# Get a list of tables involved in a process

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to run a series of queries (a couple hundred ETL statements) and get a list of which tables are selected from. Is there a way to do this in snowflake? I was wondering if I could set my connection to a certain role/warehouse and pare the information down that way or some such, but am not sure what clever ways there might be to get this information.

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the **SELECT statements** from your ETLs:

At the start of your ETL, set the QUERY_TAG or save the SESSION_ID:

```
alter session set query_tag='MY_ETL'; -- Tag queries

select current_session(); -- Or save this SESSION_ID
```

Then filter history by QUERY_TAG:

```
select * from table(information_schema.query_history());

select query_text from table(result_scan(-1))
where query_type='SELECT' and query_tag='MY_ETL'
order by start_time;
```

or by SESSION_ID:

```
select * from table(information_schema.query_history_by_session(session_id=>298348393433));

select query_text from table(result_scan(-1))
where query_type='SELECT' 
order by start_time;
;
```

---

To get **the list of tables** and other objects, you could then execute EXPLAIN for each SELECT statement returned above, and check the OBJECTS column.  (This has caveats -- fore example, it's based on the logical plan, not actual execution.)

If that's too heavy, a trick is to inject metadata, like table names, into comments:

```
select /* metadata here */ 1;
```

Then extract the metadata from the QUERY_TEXT:

```
select * from table(information_schema.query_history());

select regexp_substr(query_text, '/\\*(.*?)\\*/', 1, 1, 'e') metadata, *  
from table(result_scan(-1))
where query_type='SELECT' and query_tag='MY_ETL'
order by start_time desc;
```

But this will miss tables buried in views and functions.

---

Hope that's helpful